# How to optimize a dynamic website

Tags: seo, php, search-engines, web-development, optimization

I know there is already an answer on ***[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)*** to a part of this question ([SEO for Dynamic website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23909/seo-for-dynamic-website)) , which has been very helpful with [How to build a controller that creates an xml sitemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775218/how-to-build-a-controller-that-creates-an-xml-sitemap) on ***[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)*** about how to create a correct `sitemap.xml` for a dynamic website.

But my question is a bit more specific, I'm new with the SEO techniques and honestly it's not my field. I prefer to program for 17 hours instead of thinking about the SEO for 1 hour so I do not understand it very well but now I need it…

Thanks the researches I've realized that on the page there should be a set of **keywords** entered in the `<title> </title>` and `<h1> </h1>` tags and must also be repeated more than once in the content of the page.

**My scenario**:
I am working on a website for the sale of pet products that are organized by category (dog, cat, etc.), subcategory (dry food, meat, etc.) and brand.
In the database the product contains the title, description and picture.

The main links to my pages are:

- For the search in the categories (*performed by the user through the menu*)
  ***`example.com/search.php?sec=dog_meat_brand1`***
  which will show a series of products for that combination of categories.
- For details of the product (*when, the user clicks on a product*)
  ***`example.com/product.php?id=productID`***
  which will display the title of the product (with the picture, price, quantity, etc.) description, and related products.
- For the direct search (*when the user types it into an input box*)
  ***`example.com?search.php?q=querySearch`***
  which will display a set of products related to the research

***My questions are***:

- Is right to enter in the `<title>` and `<h1>` tag *`$_GET ['sec']`* or *`$_GET ['q']`* or *`$_GET ['id']`*? (I wonder if google, yahoo etc. take my pages as results before or after my server has processed);
- If I show the content of the page that contains some "keywords", will search engines consider these as keywords and then direct the user on my site?

…in a few words, I would like to do less SEO as possible and leave the job at descriptions and titles already written.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Automation gets a bit tricky. Normally, I suggest something conversational, but that does not always apply. The reason for something conversational is to drive click-through rates and to better perform in mobile searches which tend to be conversational. You may want to look at some competitors that are performing well to see what they are doing. You may want to see if *sec* can be worked into something more conversational or if the database schema can be reworked to allow better SEO options then I suggest that. Yeah! More code.

Comment: @JohnConde: I don’t think [it](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/23909/17633)’s is a duplicate. Over there, the OP specifically asks about sitemaps (which is also what the three answers are about).

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc for your suggestion! But I have another question: Is the URL taken into account from the search engines for indexing? (i.e. : Is there any difference for Google if the url is **`search.php?cat=29&subCat=18&brand=2`** where the numbers are the ID's of the various categories or **`search.php?cat=dog&subCat=meat&brand=brand1`**) both cases will display the same page with the same keywords

Comment: @unor, This question could be closed as dupes of other questions, too,  as the two questions they have have been covered before anyways. There isn't anything new here.

Comment: And thanks unor for your note! @JohnConde I pointed in my question that there is already an answer (there are too two links to other questions) to a part of my question but mine was a bit more specific so I was unable to ask in the comments because the length and because I have not enough reputation...

Comment: @Gersey The page URL/URI carries less keyword weight these days but still fairly important for search. If given an option between a keyword and a numerical id, I would go for the keyword. Years ago, I created an alias that could represent almost anything on my site and one of the ways that I used it is to present a single conversational parameter (similar to a page title) that aliases one or several id based parameters. It really made a difference! So ?cat=dog&subCat=meat&brand=brand1 could be aliased as ?alias=dog-food-meat-based-purina if you are that ambitious.