# Does Google index JavaScript generated HTML?

Tags: seo, html, google-search, javascript, html5

SO we are using click funnels, and it generates the HTML pages for you. When we looked at the HTML they provided, we realized that the HTML is generated from JavaScript.

SEO is a huge concern for us. We are wondering if Google indexes JavaScript generated HTML for their search results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEO for Dynamic website](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23909/seo-for-dynamic-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SO we are using clickfunnels, and it generates the HTML pages for you, but when we look at the HTML they provided, we realize that the HTML is generated from javascript through their site. ...  SEO is a huge concern for us.

Google won't be happy with indexing your site. Google likes unique content.

According to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en#quality_guidelines google states:

```
Quality guidelines - specific guidelines

Avoid the following techniques:

- Automatically generated content
```

> So we are wondering, if google search indexes javascript-generated HTML?

There are stories that they do but I wouldn't depend on it.

Also, its best if you can design your site so that *the most important parts of it are readable without the need of javascript to promote accessibility*  (For example, to allow a blind user with a screen reading program to read it).

Comment: They are not automatically generated.  We still have to create it, only we used the WYSIWYG editor.  The reason we use clickfunnel is because they track user interaction far better than google analytic, it tracks exactly the entire click through map of the user... so we can do more thorough A/B testing...

Comment: One thing I don't like about fancy editors like WYSIWYG especially front page back in the day is that they add extra unnecessary bloat to your HTML file which increases its size and therefore increases download time. Make sure you check your HTML source code for the unnecessary bloat and remove it before making the page live on the net.

Comment: **"Automatically generate d—or “auto-generated”—content is content that’s been generated programmatically. Often this will consist of paragraphs of random text that make no sense to the reader but which may contain search keywords."** - This has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) Google does index JavaScript generated content and it takes precedence over the static content it replaces.

Which makes sense considering the [first point in the quality guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en#quality_guidelines).

- Make pages primarily for users, not for search engines.

Thus how the page appears to the user is how it is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Only recently did Google start looking through javascript but no one knows exactly what they do with it. Suffice to say they aren't going to render a lot of HTML for anyone's sake. Generating HTML for most of your page is never a good idea for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a spec for AJAX (SPA) applications, https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification. basically you need to provide the server the same content, but by using classic web site (request-response) technology. I call it a core site.

Comment: Everyone please note that this spec is now outdated.

Comment: I wrote about its deprecation a couple of years ago ;) https://love2dev.com/blog/what-does-google-deprecating-their-ajax-crawling-policy-mean-to-single-page-applications/

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted anyone reading this answer to be aware.

Comment: np, its been a few years and I can't keep up with where I have older answers like these :)